# Exception when using a lock on a logger in a static class

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, locking

I am creating a simple static log class for my multithreaded apllication.
This is my log code:

```
 public static class Logging
{
    private static readonly string _logFile = "files/Logfile.txt";
    private static object _obj = new Object();
    
    public static void Log(string logMessages)
    {
        lock (_obj)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(_logFile))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(logMessages);
            }
        }
    }
```

The log method is called from multiple threads and classes.
Howerver I keep getting this exception:

```
 System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file \GUI\bin\Debug\files\Logfile.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

Does anyone have an idea what the cause or the solutions is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any chance you have multiple processes trying to do this? (A lock is single-process). Also, `File.AppendAllText` may be an easier option.

Comment: @MarcGravell it is indeed called mulitple times from 1 program but because it is multithreading it can and will happen at the same time. However it is hard to use a lock object that all methods in all classes in all threads are able to use.

Comment: Why is it hard to use a lock object that all methods, classes and threads can use? It seems that the `static object _obj` is exactly such an object.

Comment: I no longer get the error thnaks for the help! I don't know why but i think i used the lock wrong not on in this part of the code but the code calling the logging.

Answer (score 0):

I test this code in different states but don't get any error and each tasks finish after others.
that error in your result might relate to other things.

```
        var t1 = new Task(()=> Log(txt));
        var t2 = new Task(()=> Log(txt));
        var t3 = new Task(()=> Log(txt));
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        t3.Start();
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
```